# MKDIR above domain root but not host root?

Tags: php

I've a social network that I'm building a mobile site for. It's pretty much finished although I'm struggling to mkdir when a user creates an account on the mobile site in the overall host root. Is it possible?

I tried this:

```
mkdir("http://www.domain.com/image/".$mid, 0777);
mkdir("http://www.domain.com/image/".$mid."/temp", 0777);
mkdir("http://www.domain.com/image/".$mid."/preview", 0777);
umask($oldumask); 

copy('http://www.domain.com/images/default.png', 'http://www.domain.com/image/'.$mid.'/default.png');
copy('http://www.domain.com/images/default.png', 'http://www.domain.com/image/'.$mid.'/thumb-default.png');
```

But unsurprisingly it didn't work. How can I go back to the host root of the site, not the domain root? Is it possible? Any suggestions?

See the DIR layout example here:

[image: Dir]

Comment: Why are you using URL-style directory names?

Comment: That's just an example for clarity. When you go to .com and it detects it's a mobile site it redirects you to the domain.mobi domain. But the folder is just called 'm'.

Comment: It is not very clear to me what the folder structure is.  Threotertically there should be no problem copying any file to and from anywhere on the file system where the user that PHP is running as has appropriate permissions. What specific problems are you having with your implementation?

Comment: Don't use full `URL` just use `domain.com`

Comment: You really shouldn't use : or / as parts of a path..

Answer (score 0):

Echo `__DIR__` (`dirname(__FILE__)` for PHP below 5.3) in your index.php (or any other file that covers its base). It should return the full path from the server root to index.php. `mkdir` needs the server root, not the browser root.